# Can you implicitly tell Intellisense what type a variable is?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Using JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 can you implicitly tell intellisense what type a variable is?

For example could you add a comment giving intellisense a bit more info to go on.

```
/**
 * @type {Apple}
 */
var obj = tree.pickFruit();
```

I realise the comment is in JSDoc syntax, if it's possible to use that rather than VSDoc syntax that would be a bonus

**Syntax info:** VSDoc is the comment syntax Microsoft use, but it seems JSDoc is a more widespread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (at least currently) - either intellisence guesses the right type or it doesn't. If you want typing (and therefore rich intellisence), you might wanna take a look at Microsoft's TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the TypeScript suggestion, will look into that language.